# Getting all columns of a Dataframe after using 'groupby' method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Not able to fetch all the columns of the Dataframe after applying groupby method of Pandas

I have a sample Dataframe as below.

```
  col1 col2        day col4
0   a1   b1     monday   c1
1   a2   b2    tuesday   c2
2   a3   b3  wednesday   c3
3   a1   b1     monday   c5
```

Here 'a1 b1 monday' are repeated twice. So after groupby the output should be:

```
col1    col2          day     col4  count
a1        b1       monday      c1     2
a2        b2      tuesday      c2     1
a3        b3    wednesday      c3     1
```

I tried using `df.groupby(['col1','day'],sort=False).size().reset_index(name='Count')`

and

```
df.groupby(['col1','day']).transform('count')
```

and the output is always

```
col1    day         count
a1  monday        2
a2  tuesday       1
a3  wednesday     1
```

where as my original data have 14 columns and it is not making sense to keep all the column names in groupby statement. Is there a better pythonic way to achieve this??

Comment: `df.groupby(['col1', 'day'])['col4'].agg(['first', 'count']).reset_index()`

Comment: As i mentioned real data has total of 14 columns with big strings as column names, so it is not a pleasant way to keep all 14 column names in the groupby statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `groupby` with [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) to make your `count` column.

Then use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to remove duplicate rows:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['col1','day'],sort=False)['col1'].transform('size')
df.drop_duplicates(['col1', 'day'], inplace=True)

print(df)
  col1 col2        day col4  count
0   a1   b1     monday   c1      2
1   a2   b2    tuesday   c2      1
2   a3   b3  wednesday   c3      1
```

Comment: already tried drop_duplicates too(forgot to mention in the post). I am looking to get all the columns along with count of occurrences on 'day' columns

Comment: Edited answer @Kumar-58

Comment: Perfect, dont forget to accept as answer if it helped you :) @Kumar-58